# How to create a Spy for a static method called in another npm library?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Given I have a method in an Angular service like this:

```
  public logException(error: Error, methodName?: string) {

    if (!methodName) {
      methodName = this.extractCallerName(error.stack);
    }

    CommonLogHelper.Logger.logException(error, methodName, this.COMPONENT_NAME);
  }
```

Where the CommonLogHelper.Logger is located in another npm library and Logger is a static property of the CommonLogHelper class, how can I spy on that logException method?

This is what I've tried:

```
  it('should log an exception with method name', () => {
    spyOn(CommonLogHelper.Logger, 'logException');
    const error = new Error('Test error');
    const methodName = 'TestMethod';

    loggerService.logException(error, methodName);

    expect(CommonLogHelper.Logger.logException).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      error,
      methodName,
      'Schedule Web Client'
    );
  });
```

I'm getting the following error:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logException')

Answer (score 0):

What you have seems correct.

Can you `console.log` the following to see which one is undefined?

```
it('should log an exception with method name', () => {
    spyOn(CommonLogHelper.Logger, 'logException');
    const error = new Error('Test error');
    const methodName = 'TestMethod';
    // Add these consoles
    // make sure this is a class and has logException
    console.log('LoggerService: ', loggerService);
    // make sure this is not undefined either    
    console.log(CommonLogHelper.Logger);

    loggerService.logException(error, methodName);

    expect(CommonLogHelper.Logger.logException).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      error,
      methodName,
      'Schedule Web Client'
    );
  });
```

I hope the above `console.log`s help you find where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out I had to add a mock for the LoggingService static property:

```
let logserviceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('LoggingService', ['logException', 'logEvent']);
    CommonLogHelper.Logger = logserviceSpy;
```